# Writing current date to plist file using the command line

Tags: terminal, command-line, plist

I'm trying to use this command to do so:

```
defaults write test.plist LatestDate date "+%y-%m-%d"
```

where `LatestDate` is the key I'm modifying. The problem is, it doesn't recognize `date "+%y-%m-%d"` as what I'm trying to write to the key, and when I put it in quotes it simply writes that text, not the date to the key.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In defaults, date is just an option, not the actual date command. You need to actually pass the date.

```
defaults write test.plist LatestDate "$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S +0000')"
```

Comment: I'm kind of confused as to what this is doing: the normal command gives me an `unexpected argument` error, and using `-date $(date +"%Y")` gives me  `2016-10-03T10:00:00Z`. I'm fine with the Date T Time Z format, but the actual time seems kind of strange... at 10 AM it gave that and I changed the system time to 11 AM, but it still gives that

Comment: The edit I issued seemed to fix the problem

Comment: @SkeletonBow Yep, oops sorry, cheers for the edit.