# Edit a date value in plist from terminal

Tags: terminal, command-line, plist

I am trying to edit a date value in a plist to todays date.  I found a [previous question on here relating to it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255633/writing-current-date-to-plist-file-using-the-command-line?rq=1), but i get an error every time.

Here is what i am using

```
defaults write com.test.name.plist TestAppFirstSeen $(date +"%Y-%m-%d %l:%M:%S +0000")
```

This is the error i get:

```
defaults[10761:276123] Unexpected argument 11:43:25; leaving defaults unchanged.
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised the original solution ever worked, but maybe the `defaults` command changed in recent versions. Try

```
defaults write com.test.name.plist TestAppFirstSeen "$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %l:%M:%S +0000')"
```

Also, `%l` gives you the hours between 1 and 12. If you want 1 to 24 use `%H` instead.

Comment: This works!  Wonderful, thank you!

Now i need to put it into a script so i can run it whenever, can i just paste that line into a shell script, save it and just double click the script?

Comment: So i have tried this as an apple script, but it doesn't work:

```do shell script "defaults write com.test.name.plist TestAppFirstSeen "$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %l:%M:%S +0000')"```

I think its something to do with having to put " at the start of the command, after "script" but i am not sure.

It gives this error:

A unknown token can’t go after this “"”.

Comment: @hardtofin Well, within AppleScript you probably need to escape the quotes within the command.

Comment: I'm really sorry but i don't understand.  I googled escape quotes and so now have:

```do shell script "defaults write com.test.name.plist TestAppFirstSeen \"$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %l:%M:%S +0000')"```

So there is a \ in front of the "$(date, but it still doesn't work.

This is the error:

sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: `do shell script "defaults write com.test.name.plist TestAppFirstSeen \"$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %l:%M:%S +0000')\""`

Comment: Wonderful, thank you ever so much for your help @nohillside